# how should i solve this error :Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on string in C:\xampp2\htdocs\digikalamvc\core\model.php on line 53

Tags: php

```
<?php

class Model
{

    public static $conn = '';
    public $totalMenu = array();

    function __construct()
    {
        $servername = 'localhost';
        $username = 'root';
        $password = '';
        $dbname = 'digi_mvc';
        $attr = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8');
        self::$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $servername . ';dbname=' . $dbname, $username, $password, $attr);
        self::$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        if (function_exists('jdate') == false) {
            require('public/jdf/jdf.php');
        }

    }


    public static function getoption()
    {

        $sql = "select * from tbl_option";
        $stmt = self::$conn->prepare($sql);
?>
```

Comment: are you calling `getoption()` without generating a new object of `Model`? because in that case, `$conn == ''` and is not your PDO

Answer (score 2):

If you call a method statically it does not call the class constructor,

You get the error because you have this

```
 public static $conn = '';
```

As the default, which is a string, so when you call it, you obviously get the error that you get.

How to fix it, well the structure of the class is basically toast.

So either you will need to call construct first or better make the connection static and check it.

So instead of construct change that to

```
public static $conn; //change this to null, it will be a touch easier to check

public static function connect() ///__construct()
{
    $servername = 'localhost';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $dbname = 'digi_mvc';
    $attr = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8');
    self::$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $servername . ';dbname=' . $dbname, $username, $password, $attr);
    self::$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    if (function_exists('jdate') == false) {
        require('public/jdf/jdf.php');
    }
}
```

Then in the other method,

```
public static function getoption()
{
    if(!self::$conn) self::connect();
  //.... rest of code...
```

Something like that.

This way when you call  `getoption` it will check if `$conn` is not false, and if it is false it will call connect, if it's not then we have called connect from a previous call.

As a side note your missing the last two `}` one to close `getoption` one to close the class, but I take it that is just a typo in the question.

One last thing I will say, it's generally not a good idea to mix and match static and non-static methods, in some cases this can work.  But in general, they don't play nice with each other.  You get into a situation where you lose the object's state.

Another pattern that you can use is called a "Singleton" which IMO (some disagree) works fine in the case of a database class.  But I wont get to in depth about it here as you can google that pattern if you want more information.